# Proyecto Laravel 5.6. Las rutas no me funcionan, ¿que tengo que hacer en el .htaccess?

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, hosting

He subido mi proyecto a hosting compartido, ya modifique el archivo index.php y el archivo .env.

Me muestra la pagina principal (Login), pero al ingresar el usuario y contraseña no me reconoce las rutas, lo que no hice es modificar el htaccess, por que no se que hacer ahi, ¿alguna ayuda?

He visto mi archivo.htaccess y tiene este contenido:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Configure el paquete “ea-php72” como el lenguaje de programación predeterminado “PHP”.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Comment: Si utilizas laravel 5.6, haz que tu servidor utilice como fichero raíz el **index.php** que está en la carpeta **public** sin modificar nada. No olvides que las dependencias de tus librerias de laravel y vendor pueden no funcionar con una versión inadecuada de PHP del servidor. Te recomiendo hacer un **composer update** por si detecta algún problema con las mismas.

Comment: Puede que ademas de lo anterior tu problema sea al copiar/instalar las carpetas a tu servidor y que también se copiasen ficheros de **caches**. Es recomendable usar: **php artisan config:cache**. Luego: **php artisan view:clear**, y por último: **php artisan cache:clear**

Comment: Creo que la directiva `AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml` es el problema. No se porque la tienes establecida, pero aun suponiendo que funcione, en algún momento puedes migrar el proyecto o la versión de PHP y todo dejaría de funcionar, tendrías que tenerla en la lista de pasos básicos para arrancar el proyecto.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel ya te proporciona una funcional

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```